# Playing multiple sounds in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am trying to add multiple buttons to play a dedicated sound ie;button 1 plays sound 1, button 2 plays sound 2, button 3 plays sound 3, and so on. I've tried using the below code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var PlaySound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tea-pot-whistle", ofType: "wav")!)
var Sound1audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wind_1234", ofType: "wav")!)
var Sound2audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var pianoSound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Evil_Laugh", ofType: "wav")!)
var Sound3audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet weak var Btn1 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Btn2 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Btn3 : UIButton!

@IBAction func likedThis(sender: UIButton) {

    if (Btn1.tag == 1){
        Sound1audioPlayer.play()
    }
    if(Btn2.tag == 2){
        Sound2audioPlayer.play()
    }
    if (Btn3.tag == 3){
        Sound3audioPlayer.play()
    }



   /*
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"givewater", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 SoundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &SoundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);*/

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Btn1.tag = 1;
    Btn2.tag = 2;
    Btn3.tag = 3;

    Sound1audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound)
    Sound2audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: PlaySound)
    Sound3audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound2)

    Sound1audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    Sound2audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    Sound3audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

this code plays the sound but it plays all three depending on which button is pressed. I am new to swift, in objective c I had each IBAction written out for each button. Then I modified the code to tie all the buttons to a single action and I used tags to determine which button was pressed. Am I able to this type of consolidation with swift? any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your function, `sender` is the button that was tapped, so that is the button tag you should check in your if statement, but really you should use an array for your sounds. It will make your code much more compact

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit, I read it twice and it sounds like you say it does what it's supposed to do, but obviously it's not, so maybe you could make it a bit clearer? Especially this part: "this code plays the sound but it plays all three depending on which button is pressed."

Comment: Sorry, I meant when any of the 3 buttons were pressed all of the sounds in the "likedThis" function would play simultaneously. The answer provided by Lion below was spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your,

```
  if (Btn1.tag == 1){
    Sound1audioPlayer.play()
}
if(Btn2.tag == 2){
    Sound2audioPlayer.play()
}
if (Btn3.tag == 3){
    Sound3audioPlayer.play()
}
```

with

```
 if (sender.tag == 1){
    Sound1audioPlayer.play()
}
if(sender.tag == 2){
    Sound2audioPlayer.play()
}
if (sender.tag == 3){
    Sound3audioPlayer.play()
}
```

you should use sender.tag!! If you check btn.tag then every condition will become true!!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks You were right on! I have a question Paulw11 said I should put all my sounds into an array based on what I have above how would I put my 3 sounds into an array to be called by this function? sorry just thinking out loud. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome... :) m not getting what you asking! btw it's better to know it from paulw11, if he suggest it!